# How to show an external div when on hover using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any way that I can show a external div on hover of a button using pure Javascript.
In my application, there are many icons and I wanted to show a tooltip on hover that should be a external div with some text.

```
<div class="icons">
      <div class="icon-wrapper" data-label="Delete">Icon Image</div>
      <div class="icon-wrapper" data-label="User">Icon Image</div>
      <div class="icon-wrapper" data-label="Edit">Icon Image</div>
      <div class="icon-wrapper" data-label="Checkbox">Icon Image</div>
      <div class="icon-wrapper" data-label="Settings">Icon Image</div>
    </div>
```

```
<div class="tooltip">
      This external div should appened to each "icon-wrapper" div extrally on hover. This div should not be there by deault in the html body.
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance

I found many example on jQuery but I need it in pure Javascript.

This seems like simular but it's not working in my use case and its based on ID. It should be based on class and not id in my case.

Comment: `I found many example on jQuery but I need it in pure Javascript.` convert the jquery javascript to non-jquery javascript - anything you can do in jquery can be done in javascript, because jquery is javascript

Comment: I am not an expert in Javascript, how do I do that?

Comment: You could listen for `mouseover` and `mouseout` events, and do stuff accordingly

Comment: Any example please, I am struggling to do that.

Comment: Oh, so you don't know how to code jquery/javascript - that's going to be a challenge to help you - you say you want to "show a div" on "hover of a button" ... but your HTML only has `div` - no button

Comment: I know HTML and CSS, but I don't have much experience in JS. If you can show it on hover of this .icon-wrapper class name then I can do the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a simple domo,I think you need learn more about JavaScript otherwise you'll also have problems

```html
<style>
  .tooltip {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #fff;
    left: 100px;
  }
</style>
<div class="icons">
  <div class="icon-wrapper" data-label="Delete">Icon Image</div>
  <div class="icon-wrapper" data-label="User">Icon Image</div>
  <div class="icon-wrapper" data-label="Edit">Icon Image</div>
  <div class="icon-wrapper" data-label="Checkbox">Icon Image</div>
  <div class="icon-wrapper" data-label="Settings">Icon Image</div>
</div>

<div class="tooltip" style="display: none;">
  This external div should appened to each "icon-wrapper" div extrally on hover. This div should not be there by deault in the html body.
</div>
<script>
  const icons = document.querySelector('.icons')
  const tooltip = document.querySelector('.tooltip')
  icons.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
    if (e.target.className === "icon-wrapper") {
      tooltip.style.top = e.target.offsetTop + 'px'
      tooltip.style.display = 'block'
    }
  })
  icons.addEventListener('mouseout', e => {
    tooltip.style.display = 'none'
  })
</script>
```

Comment: I can add it by default, but It will impact the page speed. so this is why I am trying to do it from JS and it will display on demond.

Comment: This is something that I need, but not sure how to loop it for each div (icon-wrapper)

`const tooltipTag = document.createElement("P");
  tooltipTag.classList.add('tooltip');
  const tooltipText = document.createTextNode("I am appened Text");
  const icons = document.querySelector('.icons')
  const tooltip = document.querySelector('.icon-wrapper')
  icons.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
  if (e.target.className === "icon-wrapper") {
    tooltip.appendChild(tooltipTag);
  }
  })
  icons.addEventListener('mouseout', e => {
    tooltip.removeChild(tooltipTag);
  })`